# How can I clear the breadcrumb and set a custom one after a wizard? In Odoo 9

Tags: odoo, odoo-9, breadcrumbs

I have a wizard in a custom module.

When I click on the main button, it redirects me to my custom view and the breadcrumb is updated well, but the problem is that the previous links remain in the breadcrumb. 
I do not want to keep the previous links in the breadcrumb.

Is it possible to "clean" the breadcrumb after the wizard? (And put only the new link)

#### More info:

This is the code for the main button action of the wizard:

```py
def custom_main_button_action(self):
  ...(my stuff)...
  return {
          'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
          'name': _('My_Name)'),
          'res_model': 'my_model',
          'view_type': 'form',
          'view_mode': 'tree, form',
          'target': 'current',
          'views': [(tree_id.id, 'tree'), (form_id.id, 'form')],
    }
```

Comment: sorry but what is breadcrumb?

Comment: @CherifOdoo The breadcrumb is the path to the current view which is displayed as a serie of links. Look at this image: http://i.imgur.com/zCniZcd.png
If you want to know about the origin of the word, look at this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadcrumb_(navigation)

Comment: i don't think there is a way to do that. but is it ok when the user close the wizard to reload the page?

Comment: @CherifOdoo that doesn't solve the problem

Comment: I thought so. I'm not a javascript programmer , sorry cannot find any idea

Answer (score 0):

Hello By using below code you can manage clearing the previous breadcrumb. To clear breadcrumb we have to give one parameter named "clear_breadcrumbs" inside options dict with "True" value.

```
return {
      'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
      'name': _('My_Name)'),
      'res_model': 'my_model',
      'view_type': 'form',
      'view_mode': 'tree, form',
      'target': 'current',
      'views': [(tree_id.id, 'tree'), (form_id.id, 'form')],
      'flags': {'form': {'action_buttons': True, 'options': {'clear_breadcrumbs':True } } }
}
```

I hope this will work for you.

Comment: Nothing different happens with that option. The breadcrumb still there with the old information...

Answer (score 0):

I know that this question was from 2 years ago but it is really good to answer it. you need to change the value of **target** (optional).

whether the views should be open in the main content area **current**, in full screen mode **fullscreen** or in a dialog/popup (**new**). Use **main** instead of **current** to clear the breadcrumbs. Defaults to current.

from there https://www.odoo.com/documentation/11.0/reference/actions.html#window-actions-ir-actions-act-window

```python
def custom_main_button_action(self):
  ...(my stuff)...
  return {
          'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
          'name': _('My_Name)'),
          'res_model': 'my_model',
          'view_type': 'form',
          'view_mode': 'tree, form',
          'target': 'main', # Target
          'views': [(tree_id.id, 'tree'), (form_id.id, 'form')],
    }
```

Comment: Maybe in Odoo 11 works fine, but in Odoo 9 doesn't. I put 'main' instead of 'current' and the behaviour is the same. The breadcrum is not cleared.